# Generate Google Cloud Endpoint Lib Failure with SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin, maven-gae-plugin

Google app engine sdk version is 1.8.9
Google Plugin for Eclipse with https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3
OS version is windows 7 x64
Language is English

Try to use the eclipse 4.3 to create the Guestbook sample as https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/

The sample project can be build/deploy successfully. And the API also is tested ok.

But when try to use the google->generate cloud endpoint client libary, it will prompt an error, the error trace is as below (PS: Also tried with command line, still failed.):

```
 - Error Details --
Date: Mon Feb 10 20:47:49 CST 2014
Message: Unexpected Exception
Severity: Error
Product: Eclipse 2.0.0.20130613-0530 (org.eclipse.epp.package.mobile.product)
Plugin: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm
Exception Stack Trace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:144)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3047)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.IoUtil.copy(IoUtil.java:57)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.copyJar(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:88)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:142)
    ... 4 more
Root exception:
com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:144)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3047)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.IoUtil.copy(IoUtil.java:57)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.copyJar(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:88)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:142)
    ... 4 more
```

The code is simple as below:
Greetings.java:
    package com.test.guestbook;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.inject.Named;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
/**
 * Defines v1 of a helloworld API, which provides simple "greeting" methods.
 */
@Api(name = "helloworld", version = "v1")
public class Greetings {
  public static ArrayList<HelloGreeting> greetings = new ArrayList<HelloGreeting>();

  static {
    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("hello world!"));
    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("goodbye world!"));
  }

  public HelloGreeting getGreeting(@Named("id") Integer id, User user) {
    return greetings.get(id);
  }


}
```

HelloGreeting.java

```
package com.test.guestbook;

public class HelloGreeting {
     public String message;

      public HelloGreeting() {};

      public HelloGreeting(String message) {
        this.message = message;
      }

      public String getMessage() {
        return message;
      }

      public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
      }
    }
```

Comment: maybe there is an error within the endpoint declarations. the error messages from the plugin are not really meaningful. Can you add the endpoints class for more informations?

Comment: I also upload the sample code in here, it is pretty simple as the sample code in google.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_KB_A5-0X3d3pvV1dwQk1oU0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nipper, I have post the endpoint code also, thank you for your comments, this issue has made me unsleepble now.

Comment: sample code works, do you have installed the latest Google Plugin (3.5.1)? Maybe clean the project build. sorry

Comment: @Nipper, Yes, it is 3.5.1, I ask a friend also tested in his ENV, it also failed. I guess there is something I have missed in my code or configuration files.

Comment: @Nipper, the issue is resolved, it might be caused by China's GFW, it block google some speical URL, I have a friend who help me to test my project in JP, it can work fine now.